# How do I correctly typehint `cv2` and `numpy` interaction?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to typehint the following code which is supposed to convert PNG images (as bytes) to NumPy arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

def png_to_numpy(blob: bytes) -> np.typing.NDArray[np.uint8]:
    nparr = np.frombuffer(blob, np.uint8)
    return cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

However, `mypy` does not accept this code with the message `Returning Any from function declared to return "ndarray[Any, dtype[unsignedinteger[_8Bit]]]`. I fail to see how I'm supposedly returning `Any`, especially sind `imdecode` is supposed to be returning `cv2.typing.MatLike`.

Where is my mistake and how do I typehint this properly?

EDIT: `cv2.imdecode` has two overloads defined in the typings:

```
@typing.overload
def imdecode(buf: cv2.typing.MatLike, flags: int) -> cv2.typing.MatLike: ...
@typing.overload
def imdecode(buf: UMat, flags: int) -> cv2.typing.MatLike: ...
```

However, if I reveal the type of `cv2.imdecode`, `cv2.typing.MatLike` is missing and replaced by `Any`:

```
Revealed type is "Overload(def (buf: Any, flags: builtins.int) -> Any, def (buf: cv2.UMat, flags: builtins.int) -> Any)"
```

I also can't use `cv2.typing.MatLike` directly, only via `from cv2.typing import MatLike`. Seems like this might be the culprit.

EDIT2: opened an [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/901) upstream in hope of clarification.

Comment: Maybe this [doc](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports) is relevant. If you get missing imports, `mypy` will assume the type of that module is `Any`

Comment: empty `cv::Mat()` may be translated into `None`. do not expect the whole world to provide stubs typed to the level of detail that would leave you satisfied. -- you might wanna investigate this "MatLike" thing.

Comment: What version of opencv are you using? Reading the issue tracker, it seems like types are a recent feature: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/869

Comment: @NickODell I'm on 4.8.0.76, so that problem is not the issue. Besides, `mypy` can resolve types from `cv2`.

Comment: @wu1meng2 `mypy` can resolve both `numpy` and `cv2` types referenced from my code, however, it seems like it can't resolve `MatLike` from within `cv2`'s types. Will update the question and investigate in that direction.